# Upper triangular matrices $B$ that commute with every upper triangular matrix commuting with $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I remember being told that this was true by a professor, but I haven't been able to find a source for it yet.

In the theorem as stated, $\mathbb{F}$ is any field and $T_n(\mathbb{F})$ denotes the algebra of upper triangular $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}$.

> **Theorem:** Let $A,B\in T_n(\mathbb{F})$ be such that for all $X\in T_n(\mathbb{F})$, $$AX=XA\implies BX=XB$$ Then $B=p(A)$ for some $p\in \mathbb{F}[t]$.

If we replace $T_n(\mathbb{F})$ by $M_n(\mathbb{F})$, the question is answered in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1945-51-08/S0002-9904-1945-08386-4/S0002-9904-1945-08386-4.pdf). Unfortunately, the argument doesn't seem to translate directly, as I can't find a way to force the $M_i$ maps to be upper-triangular.

**Update:** I have re-asked the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304568/if-a-b-are-upper-triangular-matrices-such-that-ax-xa-implies-bx-xb-for-upper?noredirect=1#comment759533_304568) on MO. Thanks to David E Speyer, we now know that this theorem is false. In particular, if 
$$A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&0&1\\ &0&1&0\\ & &0&0\\ & & & 0\end{array}\right]$$
then the matrices commuting with $A$ are those of the form
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}a&0&*&*\\ &b&*&*\\ & &b&0\\ & & & a\end{array}\right]$$
The matrix
$$B=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&0&1\\ &0&0&0\\ & &0&0\\ & & & 0\end{array}\right]$$
commutes with all matrices of this form, but is clearly not a polynomial in $A$.

Comment: It is not considered good form to cross post, https://mathoverflow.net/q/304568/31729

Comment: And what's your question then? Sounds like you have answered your own question......

Comment: @copper.hat I am sorry. I did not know that cross-posting was poor form. I will delete this question tomorrow when the bounty ends. (Apparently I can't delete questions with bounties on them.) Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @Spot: Just informing of the site etiquette, not a criticism. I have broken most rules inadvertently (and some knowingly!).

Comment: but .. what is the exact meaning of ".. for **all** X" then ? because the counterexamples you are citing do not involve **all** the UT matrices , or did I loose something in understanding the statement?

Comment: @copper.hat Ah, thank you. I will leave this question up, but will avoid cross-posting in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This is a CW post to note that I answered this question on MO. If someone upvotes this answer, the question will be removed from the unanswered list (and, since it is CW, I will not get extra rep).